# What is solubility of silver oxide in NaOH and KOH

Tags: solubility, silver

What is solubility of silver oxides ($\ce{AgO}$ and $\ce{Ag2O}$) in $\ce{NaOH}$ and $\ce{KOH}$?

How much of silver oxide can dissolve in 1 liter of $\ce{NaOH}$ or $\ce{KOH}$?

Answer (score 2):

Silver(I) oxide is soluble in alkali solution and may contain corresponding dihydroxoargentate(II)  in solution or form silver hydroxide. This can be used to describe the amphoteric character of silver(I) oxide as it also reacts with acid to form silver chloride.

$$\ce{Ag2O + 2NaOH <=>[H2O] 2Na[Ag(OH)]}$$

[Source](http://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-1589)

$$\ce{Ag2O + 2KOH <=>[H2O] 2K[Ag(OH)2]}$$

[Source](http://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-2510)

[This paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01333a016?journalCode=jacsat) discuss the solubility of silver(I) oxide in water, alkali and alkaline salt solution and thus form silver hydroxide and thus describe the amphoteric nature.

[This link](http://m.jes.ecsdl.org/content/108/9/813.abstract) describes how much silver(I) and silver(II) oxide is soluble in alkali solution and very much answers your question.

> The solubility of $\ce{Ag2O}$ and $\ce{AgO}$ in alkaline electrolytes
>   has been studied with a polarographic technique, using a rotating
>   platinum electrode. Only amonovalent (and no divalent) silver species
>   could be detected in solutions which had been in intimate contact
>   with $\ce{AgO}$ powder over prolonged periods of time.
>
> Quantitative measurements of the solubility
>   of $\ce{Ag2O}$ in $\ce{KOH}$ solutions ranging from 1–14 moles per
>   liter, were carried out utilizing a potentiometric titration method.
>   The solubility has a maximum at about 6N $\ce{KOH}$ where it reaches a
>   value of $\ce{4.8 \times 10^{−4} N}$.

Silver(II) oxide is not as stable and readily available as silver(I) oxide. In fact, it is made by [oxidizing silver(I) oxide by ozone on alkali solution.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0277538700809833)

> The oxidation by ozone of a suspension of silver or silver oxide in an
>   aqueous solution of sodium hydroxide is described. It has been shown
>   that the oxidation proceeds in two steps:
>
> $$\ce{AgO3→Ag2OO3→AgO}$$
>
> The experimental results are in good agreement with a mechanism of
>   dissolution and precipitation. The silver (II) oxide obtained has
>   remarkable properties of stability in alkaline solution and of
>   reducibility to metallic silver. These special properties are probably
>   due to the large size of the particles.

Answer (score -4):

I really, really doubt you want to know what you are asking. Perhaps you don't understand that both (Na or K)OH are *solids* at STP and attempting to dissolve silver oxide into them would be *extremely* difficult.  If they were heated to well above their melting point (318° & 360°C, respectively), then you could mix the powdered oxides in, but then I would expect silver oxide would *not* dissolve in the molten liquids, but rather react.  However, be warned, this is a speculation on my part. In other words, if I'm correct, at STP there is no "solution" of Ag<sub>1,2</sub>O in (Na or K)OH. (STP = standard (laboratory) temperature & (air) pressure). If you meant an *aqueous* solution of the hydroxides, and yet didn't specify their concentrations, then again you need to learn some chemical fundamentals. The exact nature of a mixture of the oxides and the hydroxides at room temperature? IDK. In fact, by AgO, do you mean Ag<sub>4</sub>O<sub>4</sub>? which is a mixed (+1, +3) oxide? In the aqueous state, the mixed oxide wouldn't exist, making the question quite problematic on several different levels.