# Identification for qualitative analysis

Tags: coordination-compounds

[image]

The flow chart is indicative of a compound with a silver cation, because $\ce{Ag+}$ reacts with $\ce{I-}$ to form yellow $\ce{AgI}$. Since $\ce{Ag+}$ does not form a hydroxide complex, it forms the brown $\ce{Ag2O}$ precipitate with excess $\ce{NaOH}$ solution. With $\ce{BaCl2}$, $\ce{AgCl}$ white precipitate forms. When excess $\ce{NH3}$ solution is added to that mixture, the soluble complex ion $\ce{Ag(NH3)2+}$ forms.

So, I can choose between answer choices A and B. However, I am not sure which cation is correct. The answer key says the answer is A, but I am not sure why, because both form white precipitate with $\ce{BaCl2}$.

Comment: 1. [When $\ce{Ag^+}$  reacts with alkali, it do form a complex, but the formula is too complicated to define. So we write $\ce{Ag2O.xH2O}$ for simplicity.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86771/reaction-between-silveri-hydroxide-and-an-alkali/86778#86778) 2. I am pretty sure you meant anion($\ce{NO3- , SO4^2-}$) in the 2nd para.

Comment: @NilayGhosh Yes, the edits are correct. However, what is the correct anion?

Comment: Both the salts satisfy all the conditions. It's the cation($\ce{Ag+}$) that matters not the anion.

Comment: @NilayGhosh so there are two answers?

Comment: Seems like 2 answers.